# Jquery/PHP $.post not working with SheepIT fields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a calculator using the [Jquery SheepIT plugin](http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?sec=demo3&lng=en_GB).

SheepIT clones input fields, which I have working fine. After generating these fields I want to post a total of fields with JQUERY using something like this:

```
    [SheepIT generated fields with names and values]                

    <script>
    function calc() {
        $.post('process/calculate-charges.php', $("form").serialize(), function(data) { $('#result').html(data); });
    }
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="Calculate Total" onclick="calc()" />
    <div id="result"></div>
```

My problem is jquery will not $.post the fields that have been cloned/dynamically generated with SheepIt! It's only posting the fields that were there on the page when the page first loaded.

When i manually put a form around the fields and submitted them straight to a php file the $_POST array contains all the fields (from SheepIT!) like I need it to. I just want Jquery to give me the same results as this does.

Can anyone provide any advice or an example. Thank you. If you require any additional information please let me know.

Comment: Hard to help you: what is the code that is being spit out for the form, check the post action with firebug/inspector - is any data being sent?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to the problem anyway. Turns out I had a conflict within scripts. I downloaded an older version of Sheep IT and everything is posting as it should be now.